# Angular 7 base href slash at the end won't load

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing the following problem:

Every time I have this in my **index.html** `<base href="/example/">` and I run it like `ng serve --port whatever...` it won't load the page, it's just blank.

However, if I change it to `<base href="/example">`, without the trailing slash at the end and run it with the same `ng serve` command, it loads perfectly.

I would like to solve this issue without having to change anything in the actual code, meaning I would like the solution to be some flag at the `ng serve` command or something similar.

Is this possible? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command.

```
ng serve --base-href=/example/
```

Comment: not working, tried this already